# Can someone tell me the meaning of the following statement used in C# Code?

Tags: c#

I need to know how to interpret the following,

`var diff = orignalConfigFile.Where<KeyValuePair<string, List<ConfigurationValue>>>(x => !newConfig.Contains(x) || !x);`

Here `orignalConfigFile`, `newConfig` is a dictionary. `ConfigurationValue` is a Class.

What confused me is the statement `(x => !newConfig.Contains(x) || !x)`
x something not containing x for newConfig and x itself.

Comment: What is `newConfig`? An instance of `ConfigurationValue`?

Comment: Does that really compile? Because `x` should be a `KeyValuePair<string, List<ConfigurationValue>` which is clearly not convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter interesting i'm also unable to let it work facing the same problem

Comment: Are you overloading the operator `!` for `KeyValuePair<string, List<ConfigurationValue>` ?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that the class is [implicitely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) convertible to `bool` that's why this compiles: `|| !x`.

```
public static implicit operator bool(ConfigurationValue me)
{
   return me.BoolProperty;
}
```

In general that is not best-practise. You should use implicit conversions very rarely since it is difficult to understand and prone of errors.

[**MSDN guidelines on Conversion Operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229032.aspx):

- DO NOT provide a conversion operator if such conversion is not clearly expected by the end users
- DO NOT provide an implicit conversion operator if the conversion is potentially lossy.
  For example, there should not be an implicit conversion from Double to Int32 because Double has a wider range than Int32. An explicit conversion operator can be provided even if the conversion is potentially lossy.....

Comment: That "!x" in lambda made me to confuse also. I suppose you have the point

Answer (score 1):

`x => !newConfig.Contains(x) || !x` means:

The currently checked item in the originalConfigFile is x.
That particular x is not in the newConfig collection, or it is false, or x overloads the ! operator, and it returns false.

Comment: C# does not interpret null as false like C/C++ does.

Comment: Too much not-c# for me I guess. Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

`x => !newConfig.Contains(x) || !x` is a [lambda expression](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx&ei=mSQXUvq_OKaSiQLLsoHwDw&usg=AFQjCNFMGbuz9iVuk8Goxopu69u8923Gpw&sig2=eyPLCWHxhOTBsxeJay0YWw&bvm=bv.51156542,d.cGE) , which is a syntax that represents a delegate. In this case, the delegate is a function that will evaluate to a Boolean, true if newConfig does not contain x or if x is false, where x is each object returned by the enumeration of orignalConfigFile.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
X=> stands for Anonymous Method Which is used to Iterate the Result instead using foreach loop..
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `newConfig` is a `List<ConfigurationValue>` And `!newConfig.Contains` means `x` is not in the `newConfig list` .